# C++ threads: how to determine currently available heap, to avoid running out

Tags: c++, linux, embedded, c++14, heap-memory

The thread I am looking at has about pre-configured heap size of 32,000 KBs (the process it belongs rather). In this thread, I am looking to alloc about 320kb within a method, that is not often called. I know percentage wise my need is pretty small, but still I want to minimize the chance of running out. And I am not the only thread in this process, but only I use that method. Basically like to understand heap availability, would I reach a high watermark etc.
Thanks All, appreciate any hints.

Comment: You'll have to use some platform specific API to figure out the currently available heap - or just set a limit for your program and use your own allocators in the containers you use.

Comment: Heap is not specific to thread, you question does not make much sense